# sqoop error when export data from hdfs to mysql

Tags: sqoop

I have imported data from mysql to hdfs successfully with avro file. But when I export data back

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila --username root --password P@ssword --table actor --export-dir /hdfs/mysql/actor
```

I got the error

```
ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:590)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:57)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1606)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:904)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:763)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:786)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:289)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:260)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:246)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:327)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1872)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1671)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:106)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:63)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:99)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

How can I fix it ? (I use sqoop 1.4.7 and hadoop 2..9.0, jdk 1.8.0)

Many thanks

Comment: I don't see any issue with the sqoop command. give it one more try?

Comment: I tried many time and searched this issue before but cannot found any solution